# What does a spark cluster means?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have used spark on my local machine using python for analytical puproses.

Recently I've heard the words "spark cluster" and I was wondering what it is exactly?

Is it just Spark running on some cluster of machines ?

And how can it be used on cluster without Hadoop system? Is it possible? Can you please describe?

Comment: Cluster of machines, yes. I'm fairly sure [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html) can answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache spark is a distributed computing system. While it can run on a single machine, it is meant to run on a cluster and to take advantage of parallelism possible utilizing the cluster. Spark utilizes much of the Hadoop stack, such as the HDFS file system. However, Spark overlaps considerably with Hadoop distributed computing chain. Hadoop centers around the map reduce programming pattern, while Spark is more general with regard to program design. Also, Spark has features to help increase performance.

For more information, see https://www.xplenty.com/blog/2014/11/apache-spark-vs-hadoop-mapreduce/

Comment: I just want to clarify that Spark does not replace Hadoop in any way. It can work on top of Hadoop or separate from Hadoop.

Comment: I will edit to correct. Thanks.